# Push to heroku: no module named 'channels'

Tags: django, heroku, django-channels

I am facing this error when I add 'channels' into INSTALLED_APPS

```
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 351 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing requirements with latest Pipenv…
remote:        Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (36121f)…
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
remote:            django.setup()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
remote:            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
remote:            app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
remote:            module = import_module(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'channels'
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

What have I tried so far:

I disable the collectstatic and it is able to push the code to heroku but server is crashed

uninstall the channels and install again

Can anyone give me some tips,thank you.

Comment: Is it in your requirements.txt? Show that file.

Comment: i found it in the requirement.txt, list as below
asgi-redis==1.4.3
asgiref==1.1.2
astroid==1.5.3
attrs==17.2.0
autobahn==17.9.3
Automat==0.6.0
certifi==2017.7.27.1
channels==1.1.8
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.3.9
constantly==15.1.0
daphne==1.3.0
decorator==4.1.2
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==1.11.6
flake8==3.4.1
hyperlink==17.3.1
idna==2.6
incremental==17.5.0
ipython==6.2.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
isort==4.2.15
jedi==0.11.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1

Comment: sorry for the unclear format....please see below

![Valid XHTML](https://imgur.com/a/kbHIO).

Comment: @Kaspar did you add `channels` to `INSTALLED_APPS`? Please show your `settings.py`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem was due to the fact I used **django-channels** (there is also **django_channels**) instead of **channels**.

The right package for django channels is in fact **channels**.

So just do this:

1. List all installed packages with **channels** in there names

> pip list | grep channels

output:

> channels (1.1.6)
>
> channels-api (0.4.0)
>
> django-channels (0.7.0)

2. Uninstall each of them(even channels) by using  pip uninstall package-name:
   ex: pip uninstall django-channels
3. Reinstall only channels (witch is called **channels** not *'django-channels' or 'django_channels'*) package using:

> pip install channels

4. Create **requirements.txt** using:

> pip freeze > requirements.txt

Comment: thanks for reply, there is no other package relate channels..
i followed the getting started guild from heroku and not yet install other package. so i am really confused what happened...